# How to extract a columns values to create a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet with the following columns:
`caseid`, `first name`, `last name`, `company name`, `phone number`

with 10 rows of this data.

I want to create a new spreadsheet using the `caseid` as the name of the file. Then copy the row of data into that spreadsheet.

I tried to send the contents of the `caseid` to `df.to_csv('%s' % name)` and that did not work.

I have tried various approaches found here on StackOverflow. Like:

```
for i in caseid:
    print(df.at[i,0])(flipped to 0,i to no avail)
```

My goal would be to get `caseid` to create `(caseid).csv` iteratively.

I appreciate any pointers to where I am going wrong.
Thanks!!

Update: I have made some strides:

```
for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(), 1):
print(i, row.CaseNumber)
new_csv = open('row.CaseNumber' +".csv", "w")
```

This lets me create new csv files. I can only do this 1 time. Not sure why this does not allow me to delete the files and then recreate them.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is difficult to help you without some test data,
but to maybe give you another idea try to use pandas groupby
https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

and then save the dataframe in a new csv:
*pseudocode

```
for name,group in df.groupby(["caseid"]):
   group.to_csv(name + ".csv)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. I found that I was able to reproduce the file creation by going with: df.to_csv(row.CaseNumber) and this is repeateable. So now the goal is to copy line by line the dataframe with caseid 12345 into 12345.csv.

Comment: Don't copy line by line use the power of groupby - Like I showed in the code above

Comment: Thank you for that code! It does exactly what I want to do! Just had to add index=False to lose the index number. Very much appreciated!!